# How can I loop an effect with jQuery UI effect()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want a box to blink blink or bounce over and over. I don't want it to bounce a single time. I am trying to make certain I get the user's attention.

Surely there must be a simple way for the effect to repeat indefinitely. I can't find such a way in the API.

```
$('#flashes').effect('bounce',1000)
```

Comment: There sure is. How about sharing the code you tried?

Comment: `setInterval` seems to be the solution you're looking for...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval), which will execute a function every N milliseconds:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#flashes').effect('bounce',1000)
}, 1000);
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hk9kp/1)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple Pure JS function to blink some text:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("blink");
    if (element.style.display == "none") {
        element.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
}, 500);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R9dPy/

Answer (score 2):

The recursive way:

```
function bounce() {
    jQuery('#box').effect('bounce', '1000', bounce);
}

bounce();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48qTL/)

Comment: I thought about that too, but I think this will eventually cause a stack overflow since you will have infinite recursion